# C# Заменить первое слово в строке, не затрагивая остальные одинаковые

Tags: c#

К примеру такой текст:

```
string txt = "Я пишу этот код. Я пишу этот вопрос."
```

Если ввести так:

```
txt.Replace("пишу", "читаю");
```

То получиться:

> Я читаю этот код. Я читаю этот вопрос.

Мне же нужно заменить только первое вхождение, чтоб получилось:

> Я читаю этот код. Я пишу этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int index = txt.IndexOf("пишу");
if (index >= 0)
    txt = txt.Substring(0, index) + "читаю" + txt.Substring(index + "пишу".Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю , здесь может выручить RegExp

```
string myStr = "Я пишу этот код. Я пишу этот вопрос.";
string newStr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myStr, "^пишу", "читаю");
```

Или

```
Regex reg=new Regex("пишу");
string newStr =reg.Replace(myStr,"читаю",1);
```

Comment: Первый вариант нерабочий.

Answer (score 1):

Забыл совсем про ответы. Так же сам нашел, что и применил вот такой вариант:

```
string original = "Hello world Hello";
string substring = "Hello";
int i = original.IndexOf(substring);
string result = original.Remove(i, substring.Length).Insert(i, "Replacement string");
```

Взял отсюда: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread382167.html

P/S
Regex тоже хорошо, но в моем случае не просто текст должен меняться, но и еще всякие символы, что теоретически был бы конфликт с регулярками (с которыми я не дружу).